# Testing Object.hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, jasmine, code-coverage

I have a code implementation that iterates over an `object`'s properties.

```
for (const prop in obj) {
    propsMap[prop] = prop;
}
```

But as is states, my IDE (WebStorm) adviced me to add a property check using `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` to avoid iterating over inexistant properties:

```
for (const prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        propsMap[prop] = prop;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the current tests always come with `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` being `true` and the coverage is not the best I could get and I don't know what could happen if `obj` does not actually have the property `prop`.

Comment: *"what could happen if obj does not actually have the property prop"*. the object might inherit from another object via prototype. in this case those properties will be iterated but not "own". If you don't inherit from other object  and just create your object with maybe `var obj = {...}`, then `hasOwnProperty` check is useless.

Comment: The object can come from anywhere because this is in a library I'm creating (it's typescript originally, but this is not a typescript-related issue so I didn't tag it as typescript). I think that the test isn't useless here, but I would like to know how I can create an object so that `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` will be `false`.

Comment: How about `Object.keys(obj).forEach(prop => { propsMap[prop] = prop })`? Getting coverage on that would be much easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To test this you could create object that inherits something from its prototype

```
const obj = Object.create({name: 'inherited'})
```

`name` will falsyfy `obj.hasOwnProperty('name')` check.

But there are better options to copy object. For example [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
Object.assign(propsMap, obj)
```

Also you should keep in mind that `obj.hasOwnProperty` check is error prone. For example

```
const obj = {hasOwnProperty: null} // hasOwnProperty is not a function
const obj = Object.create(null) // obj wont inherit hasOwnProperty
```

so atleast replace it with

```
const hasOwnProperty = {}.hasOwnProperty

for(const name in obj) {
  if(hasOwnProperty.call(obj, name)) {

  }
```

Comment: I can't use Object.assign because propsMap is a typescript map, that's why I used hasOwnProperty. EDIT: I don't have time to check why but Object.assign doesn't pass my current tests while Object.keys(obj).forEach(...) does.

Comment: @Supamiu You could also construct it like this `const propsMap = new Map(Object.entries(obj))`

Comment: This is the current propsMap (typescript): `const propsMap: { [index: string]: string } = {};`

Comment: @Supamiu Atleast it compiles :) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20propsMap%3A%20%7B%20%5Bindex%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20'John'%2C%20age%3A%2037%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AObject.assign(propsMap%2C%20obj)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(propsMap)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
const parentObj = {
   defaultProp: 'test'
}

const object = Object.create(parentObj, {
    prop: {
       value: 'test',
       enumerable: true
    }
}
```

The `defaultProp` property should return false in the `hasOwnProperty` check